# How would you design a system to secure log information in Linux?

Tags: linux, logging, tampering

I am trying to learn how to secure a linux servers,  I have started it with basic logging and authentication. I would like to know if anyone can steal my logging info in default mode.If yes, then how can i secure it.

I have already googling, but answers were not satisfactory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww thanks for clarification. I didn't knew about this community. I will ask question in relevant forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good point to start from is Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux). SELinux is a kernel module, which assists you in maintaining and also securing a Linux server system. For an introduction into SELinux you might look into [the red hat Linux documentation](https://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/5/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-selinux.html)

With regard to logging you may consult:

- [The Gentoo wiki about SELinux](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Where_to_find_SELinux_permission_denial_details)
- [This article by Alex Callejas](https://opensource.com/article/18/7/sysadmin-guide-selinux)

Comment: thank you. I will look into it.